# Instead of apply, how to vectorize to access class methods when classes are stored inside pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, class, methods

I have the following code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score, roc_auc_score, recall_score, precision_score
from sklearn import datasets
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

cancer = datasets.load_breast_cancer()
df = pd.DataFrame(cancer.data, columns=cancer.feature_names)
df['target'] = cancer.target
target = df['target']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df.drop(columns='target', axis=1), target, test_size=0.4, random_state=13, stratify=target)


d = {
    'model_names': ['RF', 'LR'],
    'models': [RandomForestClassifier(), LogisticRegression()]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

scoring_metrics = {
            'precision': precision_score,
            'recall': recall_score,
            'f1': f1_score,
            'roc_auc': roc_auc_score
        }

def calc_score(col, metric):
        return round(metric(y_test, col.fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)), 4)

# would like to replace the following step and vectorize the process
for metric_name, metric_func in scoring_metrics.items():
            df[metric_name] = df['models'].apply(calc_score, metric=metric_func)
```

I would like to know if it is possible to change the `for loop` and `apply` and vectorize it. I was hoping for something like this.

```
scorer_from_scoring_metrics_dict(y_test, df['models'].fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test))
```

should give me a `pandas series` of the metric used to score for each model.

Ideally, I want to have the different scores from the `scoring_metrics` dict to be found for each model in the dataframe column, and appended as a new column.

---

When I do

```
df['models'].fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)
```

I get the error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-acb17f05fec7> in <module>
----> 1 df['models'].fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   4374             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   4375                 return self[name]
-> 4376             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   4377 
   4378     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'fit'
```

Comment: In a nutshell, nope, you can't "vectorize" function calls like this. You can, though, use some parallel processing or multithreading

Comment: @RafaelC Thank you for the info. I didn't know that.

Comment: @RafaelC please add your comment as a answer if you wish. I can mark it correct. Also add why exactly it does not work like that.